# algebraic de Rham cohomology of normal crossing singularities

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology, singularity-theory, de-rham-cohomology

For a variety $X/k$ the standard way of defining de Rham cohomology $H^i_{\mathrm{dR}}(X)$ is as the hypercohomology $\mathbb{H}^i(\Omega^{\bullet}_{X/k})$ of the de Rham complex, and this requires $X$ to be smooth. Hartshorne has extended the definition of $H^i_{\mathrm{dR}}$ to singular varieties, but using techniques that are too complicated for me. So I would appreciate if someone could help me to find out if the two definitions agree in certain circumstances.

Does the naive definition agree with actual de Rham cohomology:

$1)$ when $X$ has normal crossing singularities?

$2)$ when $X$ is a curve with normal crossing singularities?

$3)$ when $X$ is a union of $\mathbb{P}^1$ with transverse intersection?

If these are not true, do we at least have agreement of the Hodge filtration $H^p(\Omega^q_{X/k})$? I'm happy to restrict to projective varieties.

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you getting that $X/k$ needs to be smooth? The definition of $H_{dR}^i(X)$ as hypecohomology of $\Omega^\bullet_{X/k}$ works just fine for any scheme of finite type over $k$.

Comment: @KReiser https://mathoverflow.net/questions/256379/naive-de-rham-cohomology-fails-for-singular-varieties or https://mathoverflow.net/questions/128853/algebraic-de-rham-cohomology-of-singular-varieties or remarks in Kedlaya's p-adic cohomology notes (from theory to practice). My (poor) understanding is that one can indeed calculate said hypercohomology, but it is not "the correct" de Rham cohomology. Am I wrong about this?

Comment: Ah, okay - to confirm, you're interested in when $\Bbb{H}^i(\Omega_{X/k}^\bullet)$ agrees with singular cohomology of $X(\Bbb C)$ and this is what you mean by the two definitions agreeing?

Comment: @KReiser as a matter of fact, I'm not certain what I'm trying to guarantee about the de Rham cohomology. Maybe I could pose the surrogate question "Is hypercohomology of de Rham complex *the right* de Rham cohomology for singular varieties as well as smooth?". It's possible that if I knew the best way to ask the question, I would already know the answer.

Comment: One of my main concerns is if I take the relative de Rham cohomology of a generically smooth family of curves, how it behaves when specializing to the singular fibers.